# Fast Enumeration loop on an array containing an NSDictionary

Tags: ios, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have an array that contains a dictionary i have to implement the search function on this array and get it to display only the typed in text in the search bar ........................

i have tried this code

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if (searchText.length == 0) {
        isFiltered = NO;
    }
    else {
        isFiltered = YES;

    FilteredData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[ParsedData valueForKey:@"FolderName"]];       
    NSMutableArray *searchData = [NSMutableArray new];
    for(NSDictionary *dict in ParsedData){

        NSDictionary *tempDict= @{@"FolderName":dict[@"FolderName"],@"ID":dict[@"ID"]}              
        [searchData addObject:tempDict];

        SearchData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:searchData];
        NSLog(@"DATA %@",SearchData);

    }

    //Fast Enumeration

    for (NSString *fileName in FilteredData)
    {
        NSRange fileNameRange = [fileName rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if (fileNameRange.location == NSNotFound) {

            [SearchData removeObject:[SearchData valueForKey:@"FolderName"]];

        }
    }

}

[listingSet reloadData];
}




 This is the data present in parsed data as below plz check out.parse data array is    getting data from an xml


 2013-05-02 15:14:19.935 DocumentManagement[423:207] PARSED DATA (
    {
    CreatedBy = 1;
    FolderName = Posteingang;
    ID = 13000;
    ParentID = 0;
},
  {
    CreatedBy = 1;
    FolderName = "my folder";
    ID = 13183;
    ParentID = 0;
 },
```

Comment: So you want to have only objects which matches the folderName in SearchData array, rite?

Comment: @Anupdas That is exactly what i want

Comment: Can you provide the data contained in ParsedData?

Comment: If that is the parsedData structure, then my answer will hold good :)

Comment: @Anupdas it doesnot searching anything

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29305/discussion-between-anupdas-and-rana)

Comment: searchData is the dataSource of your tableView rite, can you check by breakPoints if the code is getting executed?

Comment: ParsedData is the Data source for my tableview and Searchdata is the array which is the source for the new tableview that is formed after text is entered in the search bar

Comment: After running my code, can you check if there is any data coming in searchData. You are only showing part of your code, you need to make the other changes. When you are changing the dataSource, reload to reflect in your other tableView.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood you have an array of dictionaries stored in parseData array. You want to form an subArray of it matching the value `FolderName` with searchText.

You can do it using `NSPredicate`

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if (searchText.length == 0) {
        isFiltered = NO;
    }
    else {
        isFiltered = YES;

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"FolderName LIKE [cd] %@",searchText];
        searchData = [[parsedData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]mutableCopy];
    }

    [listingSet reloadData];
}
```